# TextView.mText value changed but not updated in output window

Tags: java, android-studio

I was trying to design a stopwatch app. I was told I should use handlers. But I decided to do this.

In the onclick() for start button, i put the following code.

```
public static void delay(long milli)
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milli);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



 public void startWatch(View V){
        TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

        long seconds=1;
        int hour,minute,second;
        String h,m,s,text;

        int y=0;

        for(;;seconds++)
        {

            long temp;
            temp = seconds;
            delay(1000);

            hour= (int) (temp/3600);
            h=(hour>9)?"":"0";
            temp = temp % 3600;

            minute= (int) (temp/60);
            m=(minute>9)?"":"0";
            temp = temp % 60;

            second= (int) (temp/1);
            s=(second>9)?"":"0";
            temp = temp % 1;

            text = h+hour+":"+m+minute+":"+s+second;

            time.setText(text);

        }
    }
```

I don't understand how it is logically different from the code using post() and postDelayed(). But I don't get the expected output. The text(time) simply won't change at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** - Actually, whilst the `Thread.sleep()` is bad(let me reiterate **very bad**), the true culprit in this case is the infinite while loop that blocks the UI thread.

`postDelayed()` puts the `Runnable` in the handler thread's message queue. The message queue is processed when control returns to the thread's `Looper`. That way the UI thread isn't blocked, instead the `Runnable` is run only after the specified delay time.

`Thread.sleep()` simply blocks the thread. The control does not return to the `Looper` and messages cannot be processed. **Sleeping in the UI thread is almost always wrong**.

You're better off doing something like the following,

```
public void startWatch(View V){
    final TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    final long[] seconds = {1};
    final int[] hour = new int[1];
    final int[] minute = new int[1];
    final int[] second = new int[1];
    final String[] h = new String[1];
    final String[] m = new String[1];
    final String[] s = new String[1];
    final String[] text = new String[1];

    int y=0;

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long temp = seconds[0];

            hour[0] = (int) (temp/3600);
            h[0] =(hour[0] >9)?"":"0";
            temp = temp % 3600;

            minute[0] = (int) (temp/60);
            m[0] =(minute[0] >9)?"":"0";
            temp = temp % 60;

            second[0] = (int) (temp/1);
            s[0] =(second[0] >9)?"":"0";
            temp = temp % 1;

            text[0] = h[0] + hour[0] +":"+ m[0] + minute[0] +":"+ s[0] + second[0];

            time.setText(text[0]);

            seconds[0]++;

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}
```

P.S - Don't underestimate "1000ms", you drop a frame for every 16ms that your UI thread freezes, any dropped frames result in poor performance and janky UI, whilst a frame drop or might not be immediately perceivable, it generally leads to poor user experience. [#PerfMatters](https://youtu.be/CaMTIgxCSqU)

---

Your while loop runs on the main thread (aka UI thread), since it's an infinite while loop, it doesn't allow for UI updation. So, for example, you could put the whole thing inside a background thread and only run the `setText` on UI thread, and it would work as you expect it to.

I'm just gonna add this here for the sake of completeness, **don't do this**(we're creating a thread we don't keep track of and can't cancel, most definitely not a good idea).

```
public void startWatch(View V){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            final TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

            long seconds=1;
            int hour,minute,second;
            String h,m,s,text;

            int y=0;

            for(;;seconds++) {

                long temp;
                temp = seconds;
                delay(1000);

                hour = (int) (temp / 3600);
                h = (hour > 9) ? "" : "0";
                temp = temp % 3600;

                minute = (int) (temp / 60);
                m = (minute > 9) ? "" : "0";
                temp = temp % 60;

                second = (int) (temp / 1);
                s = (second > 9) ? "" : "0";
                temp = temp % 1;

                text = h + hour + ":" + m + minute + ":" + s + second;

                final String finalText = text;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        time.setText(finalText);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, so what if the thread gets blocked? After 1000 milliseconds it should it resumes and should update my UI, right?

Comment: It won't work out like that, your UI thread would get locked up inside the infinite while loop.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a basic example of what you should be doing.

Comment: So you are telling me that the thread sleeps at Thread.sleep(1000) and won't wake up after 1 second?

Comment: Yeah I know how to use postDelayed(). Thanks anyway. The thing is what's wrong with what I did.

Comment: Actually, my apologies, I got side tracked by the `Thread.sleep`. Whilst, it is bad in and off itself, the true culprit here is the infinite while loop.

Comment: And to answer your question, your UI thread will wake up after 1000ms, but it won't have the 'time' to update it's UI since it get's iterating infinite times within the while loop.

Comment: A very simple proof for my statement would be the fact that even if you remove/comment the `delay(1000);`, the UI thread would end up freezing (since it's caught in an infinite while loop).

Comment: I am kind of getting what you mean. You say that after waking up it goes to sleep before it updates the UI?

Comment: Yes. Basically you never exit the while loop and the main thread never gets the 'time' to update the UI.

Comment: Okay. But doesn't sequential flow say that it should go to sleep(in next iteration) only  after the update(setText) statement?

Comment: `setText` doesn't immediately update the UI, it merely changes the value stored in the object created for the `TextView` (when the layout was inflated). The actual UI change occurs later.

Comment: In a non Infinite loop situation, according to what you just said, what triggers the actual change in the UI?

Comment: That's a question I'm unable to answer, that's a question only someone who has opened and read the AOSP code would be able to answer. Try pinging CommonsWare and ask him. :P

Comment: For most of us "Android devs" who don't care (too much) about how the underlying work happens, it's enough to know that we shouldn't block the UI thread.

Comment: Anyhow, I've updated my answer to explain a few more things, do take a look at the video I linked. Mark the answer as correct if it answered your question. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Does this Code run on UI thread? If yes you are Blocking your whole program with an infinite loop.

If this does not run on UI thread you can't Access a View from another thread.

I guess you are using this on the UI thread, otherwise you would already have an error.

Try running the loop in Background and send the update to a handler which runs on the UI thread.

Comment: That's the point, right? Why should I use a handler? And by Blocking, what do you mean? Because the infinite loop is not blocking my program. It is my program. I want to let that infinite loop run forever as it should. But it isn't.